# Manually update DraftJs ContentState with clicked text

Tags: reactjs

How can I manually update DraftJs's ContentState in response to clicked text?

I have a list of text item. When one is clicked I am passing that text down to Draftjs, but because I am setting the state using componentWillReceiveProps() it requires that I click the text twice to get an update.

```
 componentWillReceiveProps() {
    const activeNoteText = this.props.activeNoteText;
    if (activeNoteText !== '') {
      this.setState({ editorState: EditorState.createWithContent(ContentState.createFromText(activeNoteText)) });
    }
 }
```

**First click:** Update the App state and pass props down to Draftjs (component updates before receiving new props)
**Second click:** Now the prop is properly set and Draftjs updates (component updates with the props received on the first click)

How can I accomplish this in one pass? I know there's no componentDidReceiveProps and I know there's a good reason, though I can't claim to fully understand yet, so what's the best practices way to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using componentwillReceiveProps?.

What you can do, is have the states your setting in Draftjs i.e. editorState(Well, that's what I can make out) in its parent and whenever a list item is clicked on the click handler for that update the editorState and then pass it as props to Draft js.

Further for the condition, where you are checking if it is not empty, 
You could use the

```
       getInitialState(){
     .....
    }
```

For initialization when your component is initially loaded. So you could have a default value for editorState.